# Using "selectAllow" with dates in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to limit user selection from a range between two dates but I didn't manage to make it work. I only managed to do it routinely like how it's specified at the [businessHours documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours). Is there a way to make this work?

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    placeholder: true,
    selectAllow:{
        start: '2022-10-24',
        end: '2022-10-25',
    },
});
calendar.render();
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow - `selectAllow` expects you to provide a callback function, not an object. The callback code can then look at the selected dates and decide whether to allow the selection or not. I'm not sure where you got the idea you could just pass in a static set of dates to that option?

Comment: I wonder if you got mixed up between that and `selectConstraint` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint) which does let you provide an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ADyson pointed out, I wasn't using the correct option. "selectConstraint" did the job for me, I already had tried it but I did send the dates as Strings, not as Dates objects.

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    placeholder: true,
    //this worked!
    selectConstraint:{    
        start: Date.parse('2022-10-26T00:00:00'),
        end: Date.parse('2022-10-28T24:00:00')
    },
});
calendar.render();
```